# same fk in different tables hierarchally

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Today I have this structure...

tableA.id

tableB.id
tableB.tableAId (fk)

tableC.id
tableC.tableBId (fk)

Is it correct I put a fk in tableC refering to tableA ? If I dont do that, I need to join tableC with tableB to go to tableA. I am telling to avoid joins and going to do all with the good pratices.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with joins, databases are designed to use joins efficiently if you index properly.  Don't denormalize unless you have a performance problem because you can get data ingerity throroughly hosed up if you don't put triggers inplace to keep all teh refernces the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple foreign keys is in no way a bad thing to do. If there's a relation between table A and table C, and you're going to need to pull data that relates to both without necessarily needing table B, having a foreign key between A-C is perfectly fine!